# Sorting a Query Fos Elastica

Tags: foselasticabundle

I have a Query to matchAll product in ElasticSearch. It run perfeclty but I want to add a Sort for this Query. I don't find example which run and I don't understand why it generate error.

This code for sorting query :

```
        $match = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();

        $query = new \Elastica\Query($match);
        $query->addSort([
            'product.price' => ['order' => 'asc']
        ]);
        return $this->find($query);
```

Generate this error :

> Error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code
>   [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])

I try lot of thing before post this but the error is always the same.

**ElasticSearch** : 5.2.2

**FosElasticaBundle** : 3.2.2

**PHP** : 5.6.30

**Symfony** : 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that is a incompatibility between ES, Elastica and FosElasticBundle. Warning ES and base PHP labrary Elastica...

this code run perfectly :

```
$query = new Query();
$queryRange = new \Elastica\Query\Range('product.price', array('gt' => 0, 'lt' => 20));
$query->setQuery($queryRange);
return $this->find($query);
```

**ElasticSearch** : 1.7.4

**FosElasticaBundle** : 3.2.2

**PHP** : 5.6.30

**Symfony** : 2.8